# Unable to receive form data in web api c#

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am trying to send the uploaded excel file to web api using XMLHttpRequest but all I receive in web api is an object. How to receive uploaded file in web api?

```
 upload(file: File): void {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData.append("uploads", file, file.name);
        xhr.open('POST', this._expenseServiceUrl + 'expenses' + '/' + 'massupload', true);
        xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Web API

```
        [Route("massupload")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage MassUpload([FromUri] dynamic uploads)
        {
            try
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");

Answer (score 0):

You can read the uploaded file from `Request.Files`

```
foreach (string fileId in Request.Files)
{
   HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileId] as HttpPostedFileBase;
}
```

Also, you have decorated your `uploads` parameter with `FromUri`. You could also change that to `FromBody` as your file is in your POST body, not the URI.

Comment: Request.Files count is coming zero.